# Multiple promise resolve in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, chaining, resolve

I have this multiple promise request that needs to be resolved before continuing next set of requests.

If the printItemList length is 1, it works fine. But the problem starts hapenning when its more than 2.

The idea is to fire print_label once the previous print_label is resolved successfully. Right now its getting fired immediately and not waiting for previous request to finish.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
function print_batch(printItemList){

    var chain = $.when();
    var arr = [];
    for(var batch_size = 0; batch_size < printItemList.length; batch_size ++){

        (function(i){
            chain = chain.then(function() {
                $.when.apply($, arr).done(function(){
                    arr = print_label(printItemList[i]);
                });
            });
        })(batch_size);

    }
}

function print_label(selectedRow) {

    var d = $.Deferred();
    var chain = $.when();
    var arr = [];
    var request = buildLabel(selectedRow);
    var noOfLabel = parseInt(selectedRow.labelCount);

    var url = 'API_URL';
    var epos = new epson.ePOSPrint(url);

    for (var count = 0; count < noOfLabel; count++) {

        (function(i){
            chain = chain.then(function() {

                var def = sendRequest(selectedRow, epos, request);
                arr.push(def);
                return def;
            });
        })(count);

    }
    return arr;

}

function sendRequest(selectedRow, epos, request){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    epos.send(request);

    epos.onreceive = function(res) {

        return deferred.resolve(res);
    }
    epos.onerror = function(err) {

        return deferred.reject();
    }
    return deferred.promise();

}
```

Comment: You are calling when.apply multiple times, once per iteration.  Nothing about executing a when.apply prevents future when.apply from running asynchronously.

Comment: But I still need to make sure in one batch iteration whether multiple print_labels got resolved or not,  right.?

Comment: I'm not completely up to speed on your entire programatic needs.  I'm simply pointing out a logical flaw.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The goal is to finish each print_label before another print_label starts. However, each print_label has multiple labels to print. That's why I'm returning an array of promise from print_label .

Comment: Never use `done`, always use `then`. Also don't forget to `return` the promises from your `then` callbacks, otherwise there won't be any chaining.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function print_batch(printItemList){
  //create recursive method
  function print_next_label(index) {
    //if we have not reached the end of the list, do more work
    if (index < printItemList.length) {
      //call the method, wait for all the promises to finish
      $.when.apply($, print_label(printItemList[index])).done(function(){
        //now that they are done, try to print the next label
        print_next_label(++index);
      });
    }
  }
  
  //start the recursive method loop with index 0
  print_next_label(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Taplar for this. This is impressive. I was just wondering, if we have more deep async request, how can we make sure every request resolves properly and runs sequentially. Just a thought.

Comment: What do you mean more deep?  Given the nature of asynchronous processing, if you want to enforce an order, you have to follow a pattern such as this.  Only executing the next step after the previous step has finished, by using either the single promise callbacks or using $.when like you are here to wait for a batch to finish before starting the next batch.

Comment: This make sense. By deep I meant, one promise is waiting for another to finish and so on. And this happens in a loop.

Comment: Ok, so the point here to remember is that normal loops are not usually practical with asynchronous behavior, because you are trying to mix procedural logic with non-procedural logic.  Recursive looping typically, from my experience, is a much better fit with the asynchronous paradigm.

Comment: Thanks. This would really help me in future